# Taking arbitrary list of objects and initializing all of them

Tags: c#, list, object

```
        bgList.Add(bg1);
        bgList.Add(bg2);
        bgList.Add(bg3);
        bgList.Add(bg4);
        bgList.Add(bg5);

        //Initialize all background objects
        for (int i = 0; i < bgList.Count; i++)
        {
            bgList[i] = new Sprite();
            bgList[i].Scale = 2.0f;
        }
```

Is this a legitimate way to do this? Basically, the question boils down to "Can I initialize a list of objects using a for loop?

I'm getting "This Object will never not be null" warnings on the bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, and bg5 objects, and that's making me wonder if this technique isn't allowed.

Comment: What are `bg1` through 5 for?  You're adding them to the list and then immediately overwriting them with new `Sprite`s.

Comment: _"This Object will never not be null"_? What do you use to have this warning?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin: I'm now realizing that. I was thinking of it as basically a dereferencing through the list call, then a constructor on that item I added earlier. I now understand that what I'm doing in the for loop is dynamically adding an object and, in this case, overwriting my previous additions.

Comment: @CédricBignon I'm using Visual Studio, and while that isn't the exact text of the warning, that is what it means. Basically, it's warning me that I never do anything with the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements are **not** equivalent:

```
bg1 = new Sprite();
```

and

```
bgList.Add(bg1);
bgList[0] = new Sprite();
```

The latter will not assign the reference to the new instance to `bg1`. It just stores the new instance in the 0th location.

So using a collection and loop to instantiate a number of variables is not a working short-cut. You have to instantiate each variable explicitly, or use an array or collection from the first place.

Comment: Okay so to clarify: basically, after the third line of code there, I have: bg1, the initialized sprite object, and then I put it in the 0th spot of the list, and then I overwrite it with a dynamic, new, unnamed sprite object? Is that right?

Comment: Actually after the assignment to the 0th spot of the list, `bg1` itself remains unchanged, but it is not in the 0th spot of the list anymore. The 0th spot is now containing a fresh instance of `Sprite`, changing which will not affect `bg1`.

Answer (score 0):

a foreach would be easier for sure, and y you should be able to do it, but imo you can also add the items in the loop something like.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < bgList.Count; i++)
        {
            var bglistitem = new Sprite()
            bhlistitem.Scale = 2.0f;
            bgList.Add(bglistitem);
        }
```